# Use conditionals to define the generation the user was born in depending on their input in a textbox

Tags: html, if-statement, onclick

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Generations</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowGeneration() {
    var yearBorn;
    var generation;
    yearBorn = parseFloat(document.getElementById('yearBox').value);
  if (yearBorn <= 2020 && yearBorn >= 1995) {
    generation= Gen Z;
    }
    else {
        if (yearBorn <= 1994 && yearBorn >= 1980) {
            generation= Millenial;
        }
        }
        else { 
            if (yearBorn <= 1979 && yearBorn >= 1965) {
            generation= Gen X;
            }
            }
            else { 
                if (yearBorn <= 1964 && yearBorn >= 1944) {
                generation= Baby Boomer;
                }
                }

    }

  document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = "You belong to the " + generation + " generation.";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
What year were you born? <input type="text" id="yearBox" size="6">
</p>
<input type="button" value="Click for Generation"  onclick="ShowGeneration();">

<div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am working on a web page that displays a textbox asking the user to input the year they were born. The user then clicks a button that reveals the generation they were born in. The code is supposed to use if/else statements to display the generation the user was born in. I thought I had it set up right but the button won't display the generation when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Generations</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowGeneration() {
    var yearBorn;
    var generation;
    yearBorn = parseFloat(document.getElementById('yearBox').value);
  if (yearBorn <= 2020 && yearBorn >= 1995){ 
    generation= "Gen Z"
    }
    else if (yearBorn <= 1994 && yearBorn >= 1980) {
            generation= "Millenial"
    }

    else if (yearBorn <= 1979 && yearBorn >= 1965) {
            generation= "Gen X"
    }
    else if (yearBorn <= 1964 && yearBorn >= 1944) {
            generation= "Baby Boomer"
    }           


  document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = "You belong to the " + generation + " generation.";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
What year were you born? <input type="text" id="yearBox" size="6">
</p>
<input type="button" value="Click for Generation"  onclick="ShowGeneration();">

<div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Nevermind, I figured it out.